# Log plot piecewise

Tags: matlab, logging, plot

I have a piecewise defined function:

```
y1 = 10^3 * (x/470) .^ (-5); % for x<470

y2 = 10^3 * (x/470) .^ (-3.3); % for x>=470
```

When I `logplot` it with my code:

```
x=logspace(0,5);
y1=10^3*(x/470).^(-5);
y2=10^3*(x/470).^(-3.3);
loglog(x,y1);
hold on
loglog(x,y2);
grid on
```

I get this plot:

[image]

I would like that `y1` be plotted piecewise only to the value 470 and another function plotted from there.
I know that I can set limits in `fplot` but how can I do that here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define different `x` vectors for each part of the function:

```
x1=linspace(0,470);
x2=linspace(470,1e5);
y1=10^3*(x1/470).^(-5);
y2=10^3*(x2/470).^(-3.3);
loglog(x1,y1);
hold on
loglog(x2,y2);
grid on
```

Comment: thanks. i thought i had to use the logspace instead of linspace because of the log plot!

Comment: Do you know why the function is not defined for x=10^0=1? Here is a screen: http://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/5842db-1481315293.jpg

Comment: No this is only how you space the `x`s. You could potentially still use `logspace`, but the you have to calculate the log value of of 470 but that might not be on logged spaced value.

Comment: The way it is written now this is performed first `((x1/470).^-5)` and `0^-5` is `Inf` so `log(Inf)` is `Inf`. Is that how you want the operations to performed or do you need to add other parenthesis.